# Where can I find the documentation for the logging-channel-adapter?

Tags: java, spring-integration

The reference manual only mentions it three times and does not do a good job of listing the configuration options. For example, is there a way to set the logging category?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the schema documentation for available attributes; for example...

```
    <xsd:attribute name="logger-name" type="xsd:string">
        <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:documentation>
                Provide a name for the logger. This is useful when there are multiple logging Channel Adapters configured,
                and you would like to differentiate them within the actual log. By default the logger name will be the
                fully qualified class name of the LoggingHandler implementation.
            </xsd:documentation>
        </xsd:annotation>
    </xsd:attribute>
```

Most IDE context-assist presents this documentation while creating the element.

However, feel free to open a 'Documentation' issue https://jira.springsource.org/browse/INT

Comment: Why sad? We strive to improve the documentation so I went ahead and created a JIRA issue: https://jira.springsource.org/browse/INT-2944

Comment: Is this manual the best place to look for the existing documentation or someplace else? http://static.springsource.org/spring-integration/reference/htmlsingle/

Comment: Yes; I already have a pull request open for it (https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-integration/pull/754/files#diff-3)